# Modifying the data returned by useLoaderData

Tags: reactjs

I've achieved this as follows:

```
const displayReducer=(state,action)=>{
    switch(action.type)
    {................}
}


const {loaderData}= useLoaderData() // retrieved from the initial loader method
const[displayState, dispatchDisplayState]=useReducer(displayReducer,{data:[loaderData]})
console.log(loaderData)


return(
..........
{ displayState.data.posts }
..........
)
```

I assigned the loaderData to a useReducer state and then modify this state when needed - which is working fine. My question: is there a way to modify the loaderData state directly or do I have to assign it to useState or useReducer to achieve this?

Comment: if you modify `loaderData` directly, your component will not be rerendered. `useState` or `useReducer` are perfectly fine for this situation.